# Appending some data to specific XML Tag from txt file to xml in Python

Tags: xml, python-3.x, xml-parsing, elementtree

Below is in my txt file I want to paste this in to the xml file below inside the resources tag without  tag  from txt file   Is there any way to do this I tried alot but failed I want to append it to xml file basically.

***TXT FILE***

```
<resources>
            <format fieldOrder="upper first" frameDuration="200/5000s" height="1080" id="3305" name="FFVideoFormat1080i50" width="1920"></format>
         </resource>
```

***XML FILE***

```
<resource>
        <asset id="r28" name="Poldark_S03E02_2tk_UK_Music_20170428.L" uid="1F74A">
        </asset>
   </resources>
```

Answer (score 0):

You've said you want to 'append' but I think you want to put the `format` element *within* the `resource` element. If that's correct then the important thing to know is about the `insert` method of a root element.

Here I convert strings into xml trees. Then I identify the roots of these trees. Having done that, I select the first child of the `txt_file` tree and insert it in position 0 of the list of children of the root of the `xml_file` tree.

```
from lxml import etree
txt_file = '''\
<resources>
    <format fieldOrder="upper first" frameDuration="200/5000s" height="1080" id="3305" name="FFVideoFormat1080i50" width="1920"></format>
</resources>'''
xml_file = '''\
<resource>
    <asset id="r28" name="Poldark_S03E02_2tk_UK_Music_20170428.L" uid="1F74A"></asset>
</resource>'''
txt_tree = etree.fromstring(txt_file)
xml_tree = etree.fromstring(xml_file)
txt_root = txt_tree.getroottree().getroot()
xml_root = xml_tree.getroottree().getroot()
xml_root.insert(0, txt_root.getchildren()[0])
print (etree.tostring(xml_tree))
```

Result:

```
b'<resource>\n\t<format fieldOrder="upper first" frameDuration="200/5000s" height="1080" id="3305" name="FFVideoFormat1080i50" width="1920"/>\n<asset id="r28" name="Poldark_S03E02_2tk_UK_Music_20170428.L" uid="1F74A"/>\n</resource>'
```